# How to create .aar file from Android Studio which support xamarin

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

I am trying to integrate bubbleKeyboardsdk.aar in xamarin.android but unable to get functions which are implemented in sdk, after that I have tried to make a demo project using Android Studio then made .aar file after that attached in jar folder to integrate but at that time unable to call public method of main activity.

So can you please anyone tell me what approach need to use in making .aar file in the android studio that supports xamarin.android too.

Comment: I hope you have checked this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/

Comment: @G.hakim I have read but you know my problem is that how to create .aar file from android studio which supports Xamarin android (code convert from java to c# ) and appear function in binding

Comment: Well to be quite honest AAR's are not of multiple types of some kind an AAR file is basically a Java Archive(JAR) which is Zip formatted so the AAR you have made must work unless there were some build issues when you made them!!

Comment: My .aar file successfully build but unable to get public function, If possible can you please see my code, give me your email

Comment: Sure email me the aar file on hakimgulamali88@gmail.com